# Problems getting the host with urlConnection.getOutputStream(); on my real device

Tags: java, android, rest

I am currently building an application that has to access my REST service using GET or POST queries but sometimes (not all of the times, only sometimes) when trying to connect to the host by inputing the IPv4 address I get the following error:

```
2019-11-14 14:01:22.279 30991-31089/com.example.mc.practical_assigment E/CONNECT ERROR GET USER: class java.net.NoRouteToHostException
2019-11-14 14:01:22.279 30991-31089/com.example.mc.practical_assigment E/CONNECT ERROR GET USER: [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@840301f
2019-11-14 14:01:22.279 30991-31089/com.example.mc.practical_assigment E/CONNECT ERROR GET USER: Host unreachable
```

This is the line that gives me the error, where my project brakes:

```
urlConnection.getOutputStream();
```

When using the Android Studio emulator, PIXEL 2 XL API 28  there is never an error, the connection is always established, but on my real device, OnePlus ONEPLUS A3003 sometimes the program cannot get the Host response.

I have tested the REST service previously using Postman and because sometimes it works in my app and on Postman every time, I know that the URL path is valid.
Also I tried using my Mobile HotSpot and it still doesn't fix the problem.
I have tried turning off the firewall from my computer so that the data is not filtered in any way.

It seems to me that my problem lies somewhere in my mobile phone but I do not know for which reasons bacause I cannot figure out the pattern of the occurance of the errors.
Is there something more to try?
Maybe the problem is with that type of connection when using Android Studio, should I try to use another code.
The whole example of my code:

```
try {
            url = new URL("http://" + BaseAddress.getAddress() + ":8084/ACME_Electronic_Supermarket/webresources/acme/user/login");
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            urlConnection.setUseCaches (false);

            OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream(); //point of failure
            DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(os);
            String payload = gson.toJson(user);
            outputStream.writeBytes(payload);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();

            // get response
            int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            if(responseCode == 200) {
                String response = readStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                User user = gson.fromJson(response, User.class);
                if(user.getUuid() != null) {
                    User.setCurrentUser(user);
                    Intent shoppingListIntent = new Intent(activity, ShoppingList.class);
                    activity.startActivity(shoppingListIntent);
                } else {
                    RestResponseMessage rrm = gson.fromJson(response, RestResponseMessage.class);
                    writeToast(rrm.getMessage());
                }
            }
            else
                writeToast("Error while trying to complete login - wrong response");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("CONNECT ERROR GET USER", e.getClass().toString());
            Log.e("CONNECT ERROR GET USER", e.getStackTrace().toString());
            Log.e("CONNECT ERROR GET USER", e.getMessage());
            writeToast("Error while trying to complete login");
        }
        finally {
            if(urlConnection != null)
                urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
```

The presented is a part of the code run in a class that implements Runnable interface in the run method of the Runnable interface.
This is the way of calling the class and running it in a new thread:

```
GetUser getUser = new GetUser(u, activity);
Thread thr = new Thread(getUser);
thr.start();
```

Comment: What kind of ip address? Where is your server residing?

Comment: I am using NetBeans with Java to make the REST service that I then deploy and access through the IPv4 address I find over CommandPrompt, running cmd and taking the address under the Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi. 50 percent of the time I can connect to my REST service and 50 percent of the time I get the given exception.

Comment: You did not tell where your server resides.

Comment: On my computer, I am using XAMPP, if that is the answer you need.

Comment: That your server resides on a local computer was the info i was asking for.

Comment: Are you executing that code in the doInBackground() of an AsyncTask?

Comment: It is a class that implements Runnable interface, which I then run using the code that I put on the bottom of the original question

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my phone the whole time. I enabled the function to automatically connect to better Wi-Fi signals when they are found (developer settings enabled), which resulted in my phone switching all the time between two network, depending on my position in the room/house. 
Also, upon switching the network, the applications needs to be run again, otherwise it will also fail.